# iframe only loads on click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, embed

Is there a way to use jQuery to get an iframe to load on a click, i want this as is the iframe is hidden in a div that is not viewable until clicked, so the heavy majority of users will not be viewing the iframe, and i dont want the load time to be affected by the iframe.

This is one of the few things i've tried, the iframe does not load:

```
$(function() {
var emba=1;
var embget = 1;
    $(".custemba").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(event);
    if(emba == 1) {
        emba = 2;
        $('.custemb').slideDown();
        if(embget == 2) {
            $('.appendi').append('<iframe src="/player_i.php?aid=12" height="170px" width="100%" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0"></iframe>');
            embget = 2;
        }
    }
    else if(emba == 2) {
        emba = 1;
        $('.custemb').slideUp();
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can either remove event.preventDefault or move it to the end of "else if".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

> if(embget == 2)

should be

> if(embget == 1)

And you don't need that extra event in

> event.preventDefault();

Here's a simplified version:

```
var appendIFrame = true;
$(".custemba").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.custemb').slideToggle();
    if(appendIFrame) {
        $('.appendi').append('<iframe src="/player_i.php?aid=12" height="170px" width="100%" scrolling="no"  frameborder="0"></iframe>');
        appendIFrame = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me, a tad cleaner, creating the object before appending:

#### HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="showframe">Show iFrame</a>
</div>
<div class="framebox"></div>​
```

#### JS:

```
var frame_loaded = false;
$(".showframe").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (frame_loaded === false) {
        var frame_element = $('<iframe>');
        frame_element.attr({
            src: "http://eatabagofdicks.com",
            height: "170px",
            width: "100%",
            scrolling: "no",
            frameborder: "0"
        });
        $(".framebox").append(frame_element);
        frame_loaded = true;
    }
    $(".framebox").slideToggle();
});​
```